Interpreting Green's function in Evans' Partial Differential Equations
Pictures below is from Evans' Partial Differential Equations.
$U\subset \mathbb R^n$ is open, bounded.  And $\nu$ is the normal vector of $\partial U$.   I want to get the last red box from the first two box.
What I try: From (30), there is
$$
\Delta_x u(x) = -\int_{\partial U} g(y) \frac{\partial}{\partial \nu} (\Delta_x G(x,y)) dS(y)
+\int_U f(y) \Delta_xG(x,y) dy
\\
=
\int_{\partial U} g(y) \frac{\partial}{\partial \nu} (\delta_x(y)) dS(y)
-\int_U f(y) \delta_x(y) dy
$$
when $x\in U$, namely $x\notin \partial U$, for $y\in\partial U$ there is
$\delta_x(y)=0$. So we have
$$
\Delta_xu(x)=-f(x)
$$
But when $x\in \partial U$, I don't know how to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial \nu} (\delta_x(y))$ ?
For 1-dimensional Dirac delta function, I know $t\delta'(t)=-\delta(t)$ in weak sense. But for $x\in\mathbb R^n$, I don't know how to calculate the analogue.







In fact, $G$ only satisfies the problem in the second red box in the sense of distributions, not pointwise. More precisely, this means that given a smooth $f \colon \overline{U} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f (y) = 0$ for $y \in \partial U$, we have
$$
\int_{U} \nabla f \cdot \nabla U = f(x).
$$
That's why it's written that "we may symbolically write" before the second red box.

@gpr1  Thanks. Your $\nabla U$  is $\nabla G$?  Besides,   "we may symbolically write"  means that we can't use the second red box to deal the $u$ on $\partial U$ ?

You're right, I should've written $\nabla G$, not $\nabla U$. The precise meaning of the second red box is what I wrote in the first comment. I believe the idea is to use this interpretation and advance the argument parting from it, so you are effectively using the second red box.

@gpr1  Since the measure of $\partial U$ is zero, and the second red box is in the sense of distribution, so $G$ is uncertain  on $\partial U$.  My understand is right ?

Even though you do not know the value of $G$ on $\partial U$, this is not a problem because notice that the equality in my first comment is only valid for functions which are zero on $\partial U$, so you can use the equality on the first red box without considering the first integral on the right-hand side when $g = 0$ on $\partial U$.

Let $x\in U$. Since $\delta_x$ is the convolution identity at point $x$, we have
$$ u(x) = u*\delta_x = \int_Uu(y)\delta_x(x-y)dy$$
then since $-\Delta_x G(x,y) = \delta_x (x-y)$:
$$ u(x) = -\int_Uu(y)\Delta_xG(x,y)dy $$
$$ u(x) = -\int_U\left( u(y)\Delta_xG(x,y) - \Delta u(y)G(x,y) + \Delta u(y)G(x,y) \right)dy $$
$$ u(x) = -\int_U\left( u(y)\Delta_xG(x,y) - \Delta u(y)G(x,y)\right)dy + \int_U\Delta u(y)G(x,y)dy $$
$$ u(x) = -\int_{\partial U}\left( g(y)\frac{\partial G}{\partial \nu}(x,y) - \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}(y)G(x,y)\right)dy + \int_U f(y)G(x,y)dy $$
$$ u(x) = -\int_{\partial U} g(y)\frac{\partial G}{\partial \nu}(x,y)dy + \int_{\partial U}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}(y)G(x,y)dy + \int_U f(y)G(x,y)dy $$
but since $G\equiv 0$ on $\partial U$, the middle integral vanishes, leaving
$$ u(x) = -\int_{\partial U} g(y)\frac{\partial G}{\partial \nu}(x,y)dy + \int_U f(y)G(x,y)dy $$

Cool, I think your way is better than Evans'.  Thanks.
